# As user types get the input value but only once every second (as in google's search bar)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that gets the input value every second but only when user has stopped typing.

```
var timeout;
jQuery('#icName').keypress(function () {
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(makeSearch, 500);
});

var makeSearch = function () {
    console.log("value", document.getElementById('icName').value)

}
```

How to get the value once every second even if user is still typing?

Comment: Take it out of the event handler, and use setInterval instead …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't very hard; you just restructure the code so that the timer gets kicked off if there isn't already a timer, rather than destroying the old timer every keystroke.  Here's your same code, revised to do it:

```js
var timeout;
jQuery('#icName').keydown(function () {
    if (!timeout) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            makeSearch();
        }, 500);
    }
});

var makeSearch = function () {
    console.log("value", document.getElementById('icName').value)
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="icName" />
```

This also uses `keydown` and not `keypress`, which will capture all keystrokes.

Comment: thanks this was exactly what I needed will accept answer once I can in aprox 5min due to SO rules